# Someone who studies biotechnology

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call someone who studies/majors in biotechnology?

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Does it mean one who has studied and is now qualified, or one who is currently a student?

Comment: He is an "undergraduate who is pursuing Biotechnology" 
- Bio-technologist here.

Answer (score 2):

I believe a biotechnologist refers to the career. So if you're referring to someone who studies/majors in biotechnology, you could just say **biotech students** or **biotech majors**.